# MATLAB - Force quit (CTRL+C) not working?

Tags: matlab

I run a pretty computationally expensive genetic algorithm with MATLAB. The code has been running for 3 whole days, and I am pretty sure it gets stuck somewhere, because it is not printing out the progress information for debugging purpose.

I now wish to stop it. I did CTRL+C, but no luck. The bottom left of the window still displays "Busy".

I cannot simply quit the whole MATLAB, because I need to find out where it gets stuck by inspecting the variables in the variable window.

Given the CTRL+C is not working, how can I

- stop the execution, OR
- save the variables for inspection purpose?

Comment: Are you running any MEX code?  Once MATLAB is passed over to MEX to run code, you can't use `Ctrl+C` to stop your code.  The only way you can stop it is if you quit the program.  However, if you're running native MATLAB code, go into the editor and insert a breakpoint in a section of the code where you know it's getting busy.  The code should pause at that breakpoint and give you all of the variables that are within scope at that point.

Comment: @rayryeng What is MEX code, please? It is not native, as it indeed calls a software (COMSOL).

Comment: MEX code is when you can run C code within MATLAB.  MATLAB has the ability to call C code within its environment as we know that C code will run faster than most native MATLAB functions.  From experience, MEX code does not have the ability to quit with shortcut keys while it's running if it runs forever.  I'm not quite familiar with COMSOL so I don't have any advice for you here.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks a lot, but COMSOL is developed with Java. So can I say that this is not MEX? Are there any ways that I can fetch the variables before quiting MATLAB?

Comment: OH YES.  I forgot you can actually call Java code within MATLAB as well.  Yup, definitely not MEX.  When you're running COMSOL, is it within a big loop?  Try introducing a small pause (`pause(0.01)`) before each iteration so that it'll give you an opportunity to stop execution (`Ctrl+C`).  You can also try writing a `finish.m` file and include this within your working directory.  `finish.m` will execute right before MATLAB quits.  As such, simply do a `save` command within `finish.m` to save all of your variables in your workspace to file before it quits.  Hopefully one of these will help you.

Comment: From personal experience, YES sometimes Force quit does not work when working with computationally expensive algorithms. MATLAB will actually stop running the script a few hours after you do Ctrl+C.

Comment: Same here, sometimes Ctrl+C just does not work when matlab is too busy doing code. In my experience in several problems I needed to just force matlab stop with task manager, and for sure when the code running is some external code called from matlab

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes ctrl-C stops working if you have a memory over-allocation problem -- if you are trying to allocate a matrix that doesn't fit in memory, and so virtual memory begins thrashing.

It's also likely that crtl-C won't work while execution is passed to COMSOL.

I think you have little choice now but to kill matlab and try to debug by either stepping through the code or inserting fprintf statements.